# Custom notification layout in jetpack compose project

Tags: android, notifications, android-jetpack-compose

I am working with jetpack compose. But I have not found any document about how  to implement custom notification layout with actions in jetpack compose project.

What is the proper way of implementing such layout?

Answer (score 1):

Someday, [Glance](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/glance) may support that, the same way that it does app widgets and Wear OS tiles. However, AFAIK, right now, Glance does not support creating `RemoteViews` for custom notifications. And Compose UI for Android only handles rendering a UI for an activity/fragment, not for notifications.